# What token extensions are live on mainnet?

Tags: token-2022, mainnet, token-extensions

We are planning on using various 2022 token extensions for our project, having spoken with a few other Solana developers, it seems that not all token extensions are currently working on mainnet.

Is anyone able to confirm if the below extensions are currently live on mainnet?

1. Permanent Delegate
2. Metadata & Metadata Pointer
3. Transfer Hooks

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all live on mainnet as of this writing. The only extensions that are *not* enabled are:

- Token Group
- Token Group Member

You can still configure the group-pointer and group-member-pointer extensions on your mints in anticipation of these features.

Also, for confidential transfers, although the actual transfers aren't enabled yet, you can still configure your mint for confidential transfers.